# BiztTalk mapping

Tags: xml, biztalk

I have source schema and from that schema I map  to output schema. Source schema represent Xml file and output schema represent store procedures ( I use it to insert to database)
after map and setup all ports I am able to load xml file to database.

Problem start when I have to load  xml file with missing child element whole process stop and  services go to “dehydrated state”.

I found that some data are loaded in and whole process stop when all came to missing child element in source schema.
In different xml file I can able to pass data and where are missing data I have null in database.

What I have use to insert null in database if I have missing data in source schema?

Comment: Is the database port two-way?  Any error messages?

Comment: Is the database MSSQL or Oracle? And what does the event log say?

Comment: Do you use user defined TableType as stored procedure parameter or just raw fields?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you provide the XML document containing the data to insert into the database an empty node will try to insert with an empty value. If you don't provide the node at all then nothing is inserted into that column (and you get a null).

In some projects I've had to add a second transformation before inserting the data. I used a very short xslt script to remove any empty nodes from my result.